# Mechanize: Avoid webserver locking

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'mechanize'

begin
    agent = Mechanize.new
    agent.robots = false
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
    url =  "http://www.paris.cl/tienda/es/paris/computacion/tablet/tablet-acer--iconia-b1-710-l688-7-342750-ppp-"

    website = agent.get(url)

rescue Exception => e 
    puts "Error : " + e.message 
end
```

This try to get a website, but I get this error:

```
Error : 403 => Net::HTTPForbidden for http://www.paris.cl/tienda/es/paris/computacion/tablet/tablet-acer--iconia-b1-710-l688-7-342750-ppp- -- unhandled response
```

The webserver blocks me (before I can get the website),I try changing the IP, but nothing happend.

Exists any form to avoid this lock? (Also I don't know which type of lock is this)

Grettings

Comment: You are trying to access a resource they won't let you have. It could be because you lack privileges because you haven't logged in. It could be because they don't let ANYONE read that file. We have no way of knowing.

Comment: No, it's a ecommerce site, so anyone can see that. at this moment I suprised what kind of locking are using.

Comment: Anyone can see it but you. Developing web-scrapers is a very delicate task. If you do something that puts your code's activity on their radar, they're likely to shut you down because you're consuming their CPU time and network bandwidth. Read their TOS, and see if it says anything about scraping or automated agents. Most sites do have wording banning that, because it can negatively affect the throughput for regular users.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, apparently you kicked their resource a few times as unprotected user (without proper HTTP headers) and they've blocked your IP.

happens to the best of us :)

Comment: It happens to all of us. The best of us get around it with proxies :P

Comment: How can add a proper Headers with Mechanize?